# Convert javascript array to JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, turfjs

I have a loop where I add lat/long points to polygonLines array

```js
var polygonlines = [];
for (var k = 0; k < lines.length; k++) {
  var start = [Number(lines[k].start.lat), Number(lines[k].start.lng)];
  var end = [Number(lines[k].end.lat), Number(lines[k].end.lng)];
  polygonlines.push(new L.Geodesic([[start, end]], geodesicOptions));
}
```

I need to get the array of polygonlines into a turf.polygon, I can get from a JSON data of coordinates to turf.polygon easily

```js
var turfPolygon = turf.polygon([[
  json.data.features[0].geometry.coordinates
]], ...
```

how can I get from my polygonlines array to JSON data coordinates? Or can I create polygonlines as json data and push the lines onto it in the loop? How do I add items to json coordinates I have never used json data before?

Or is there a better way?

Thank you very much

Edit:
I want to be able to put the polygonlines into the json... possibly like this. All the examples have hard coded values, but my values will change through user interaction.

```
var geojsonPolygon =
    {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data":
      {
         "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {
         "type": "Polygon",
         "coordinates": [polygonlines]
    }                                               
 }
}
```

I've never used json object before so not sure how to copy an array into the coordinates part.

Then use turf booleanIntersect which requires a "GeoJSON Feature or Geometry"

Comment: I have tried geojsonPolygon.features[0].geometry.coordinates = new Array(polygonlines); as well as looping thru polygonlines and doing a push onto a new Array but the coordinates of my json are always empty...

Comment: Looking at the doc for polygon, I see a regular array (an array containing an array containing arrays of pairs of ints), I don't see anything about inputs being JSON encoded, nor would I expect to.  Is it possible this question isn't about JSON? (https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygon)

Comment: @danh I then use the polygon in turf booleanIntersects (https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanIntersects)  which requires a "GeoJSON Feature or Geometry"

Comment: It might help if you could paste an example showing how 'JSON data coordinates' are structured.

Comment: @DavePritlove example added but the coordinates section is always empty. Sorry not up on terminology of json.

Comment: @tj26  Thanks. This may be too obvious but have you tried assigning the `polygonlines` array created in your first snippet to the property in your  `geojsonPolygon` object by a simple assignment using object dot notation: `geojsonPolygon.data.coordinates=polygonlines`. If `polygonlines` is correctly formatted, I think that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So don't use Geodesic for the lat/long point, this will do

```
var start = [vol.lines[k].start.lng, vol.lines[k].start.lat];                                           
polygonlines.push(start);
```

then

```
   var geojsonPolygon =
   {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [polygonlines]
   }

var turfpolygon = turf.polygon(geojsonPolygon.geometry.coordinates);
var result = turf.booleanIntersects(line, turfpolygon);
```

This will match poly1 in this example that is really helpful https://codesandbox.io/s/ripkk